# Adding new model to existing ones using Code First

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core

Currently I achieve the above as follows.

**Question**: Is it the right approach in order to keep the data in the exiting tables in tact. I feel I'm doing it rather a long-winded way. Any suggestions or alternate/correct ways of doing it?

1. Create a new entity (model) and a corresponding `DbSet<...>` entry in `myProjectContext.cs` file
2. Delete existing migration from VS2015 and corresponding `__EFMigrationsHistory` table from the SQL Server Db
3. Run `PM> add-migration mytMigration -context myProjectContext`
4. Comment out all the code in newly generated `mytMigration.cs` file except the code related to newly generated entity (model).
5. Run `PM> update-database -context myProjectContext`

New table (corresponding to newly added entity) gets created in the exiting Db along with new `__EFMigrationsHistory` table. Data in all the existing tables remains in tact.

**UPDATE:**

I'm following this [official ASP.NET tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/new-db) and - per their advice - have registered our context with dependency injection as follows:

**Startup.cs**:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var connection = @"Server=myDevMachine\SQL2012Instance;Database=myDb;Trusted_Connection=True;";
            services.AddDbContext<ABCTestContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
...
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not delete anything existing. You are adding right?

Steps you should be doing:

1. Create new entity
2. Add DbSet to context
3. Run add-migration
   newMigrationName
4. Run update-database

Add-Migration looks at the existing database and model and generates a migration to update the schema.

When you run Update-Database, EF checks the migration history table and runs the migrations that were not yet executed.

Comment: @junnas But running `add-migration` will create `Create Table...` script for all existing tables (because they are in the model file - and then `update-database` will try to re-create those existing tables.

Comment: Add-migration should see what has changed in the current model and generate a migration to update the DB schema. This is what it *should* do if you don't touch the migration history table or the existing migrations.

Comment: @junnas In the `add-migration` I've to supply the name of migration - and if it's the same name it complains the `the name 'myFirstMigration' is used by an existing migration`. If I use a different name it's going to create a new migration and a new entry in the migration history table related to this new migration. Then, `update-migration` will run that new migration which then will complain that `table so and so already exists etc...`

Comment: Then there has to be something wrong with your setup. But I can't guess what it could be. Have you done this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/new-db ? You could check it and see what are you doing differently.

Comment: The tutorial you referred is exactly the one I followed. I've just added an **UPDATE** section in my post above to answer your inquiry. I think you may be referring to the second `TIP` section (shown in green) in the tutorial. As mentioned in that TIP one can create a new migration. **Question**: How `update-database` command will know which migration to use (the new one or the old one)?

Comment: It checks the migration history table. That's how it knows what migrations have not been run yet.

Comment: @junnas Your suggestion worked (thank you). For the benefit of other readers, you may want to add one more liner to your response above as `Run add-migration newMigrationName` and explaining why it would work (e.g. it uses migration history table etc.). And, I'll mark your above response as an `Answer`.